# Redirect a user?

Tags: php

I need to redirect users who visit part of my site to a different website.

I do this with:

```
header('Location: http://new-site.com/');
```

My question is, should I use a redirect code too? If so what?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Upvote this if you feel the same way.

Comment: what you mean by "redirect code" ? Upvote this if you have the same question :p ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What if I don't feel the same? Damn it man, include a default case. You're confusing me.

Comment: That is the way to do it in php. Your other option is a .htaccess file.

Comment: My question is should I use a 301 or something else?

Comment: If you want to be extremely anal about it, you can use .htaccess, pass a header in php, add a meta tag to refresh to a new page, add a body onload script to change the document src, and then display a link for the new page. Eventually, the user should get to the new page.

Comment: In other words if it ain't broke don't fix it

Answer (score 1):

Different types of redirect methods has their own advantages and disadvantages.The same headers will be sent to the Users and Search engines there for it won't be any different so the PHP won't negatively effect your page rank compared to the .htaccess way.

**301 Moved Permanently**

A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301 redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website.

**302 Found (HTTP 1.1) / Moved Temporarily (HTTP 1.0)**

A 302 redirect is a temporary redirect. It passes 0% of link juice (ranking power) and, in most cases, should not be used. The Internet runs on a protocol called HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) which dictates how URLs work. It has two major versions, 1.0 and 1.1. In the first version, 302 referred to the status code "Moved Temporarily." This was changed in version 1.1 to mean "Found."

**307 Moved Temporarily (HTTP 1.1 Only)**

A 307 redirect is the HTTP 1.1 successor of the 302 redirect. While the major crawlers will treat it like a 302 in some cases, it is best to use a 301 for almost all cases. The exception to this is when content is really moved only temporarily (such as during maintenance) AND the server has already been identified by the search engines as 1.1 compatible. Since it's essentially impossible to determine whether or not the search engines have identified a page as compatible, it is generally best to use a 302 redirect for content that has been temporarily moved.

**Meta Refresh**

Meta refreshes are a type of redirect executed on the page level rather than the server level. They are usually slower, and not a recommended SEO technique. They are most commonly associated with a five-second countdown with the text "If you are not redirected in five seconds, click here." Meta refreshes do pass some link juice, but are not recommended as an SEO tactic due to poor usability and the loss of link juice passed.

more info : [LINK](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)